# Unable to import models Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download data to database from website using models. Structure of my project:

```
    -backdjango
      -app[folder]
        -__pycache__[folder]
        -templates[folder]
        -__init__.py
        -settings.py
        -urls.py
        -views.py
        -wsgi.py
        -drivers[folder]
          -__pycache__[folder]
          -management[folder]
            -commands[folder]
              -create_drivers.py
          -migrations[folder]
          -__init__.py
          -admin.py
          -apps.pyc
          -models.py
          -tests.py
          -views.py
        -node_modules[folder]
        -static[folder]
        -venv[folder]
        -.babelrc
        -.eslintrc.js
        -db.sqlite3
        -manage.py
        -package-lock.json
        -package.json
        -Pipfile
        -Pipfile.lock
        -webpack.common.js
        -webpack.dev.js
        -webpack.prod.js
        -yarn.lock
```

I'm using Django, Beautiful Soup, and WebPack. I've downloaded the ready configuration from [this repo](https://github.com/khadegd/django-webpack-starter). In drivers->models.py I have one model:

```
from  django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Driver(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

In app->settings.py I've added to installed apps 'drivers'. My problem is in drivers->management->commands->create_driver.py:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from django.apps import apps
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'backdjango.settings'
from drivers.models import Driver
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError



class Command(BaseCommand):
        

        def handle(self, *args, **options):
            self.save_to_db(name)

        def getDriver(self):
            r=requests.get(
                "http://www/formula1.com/en/drivers/lewis-hamilton.html")
            soup= BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
            name= soup.find("h1",**{"class":"driver-name"}).contents[0]
            print(name)
            return Driver(name=name)

        def save_to_db(self,name):
            Driver.objects.name.save()
```

In line with `from drivers.models import Driver` I have message `Unable to import 'drivers.models'pylint(import-error)`

I've tried to solve this problem in many ways but nothing I've found on the Internet helped.

Comment: Looks like your `drivers` folder is nested inside another app folder `app`? You could try importing like this: `from app.drivers.models import Driver`

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove `app` folder entirely, move everything in it into the parent folder 'backdjango'.

I'd rename drivers app to something more logical. Is the general project's topic FormulaOne? Then perhaps label the app FormulaOne. This isn't essential but it will save you from future confusion between `Drivers` app and it's child model `Driver`.

Once that refactoring is done, you need to migrate the database to instantiate the Driver model in the database.

`$ python manage.py makemigrations`

That should detect and generate a migration file for the Driver model.

`$ python manage.py migrate`

That should detect the new unprocessed migration file and install it into your database.

I'd delete the create_driver.py command - that's not the right django way to go about adding new records to the database. Instead, use this code, combined with your BeautifulSoup parsing:

```
from FormulaOne.models import Driver

# Now, to get a driver:
result = Driver.objects.filter(name=name).first()

# To save a driver:
Driver.objects.create(name=name)
```